# Make Jupyter extensions options persist

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have done some Google research, but I did not find satisfactory answer for a question below.

I have my own docker environment based on [jupyter/datascience-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook) image. I use some Jupyter extensions that are enabled by default when launching a Jupyter notebook server. One of them is [hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html). On the docs page there some configurable options are mentioned that I would like to change. For example option `hinterland.enable_at_start` is set to `True` by default. I would like it to be `False` for every notebook that I launch.

My question is: **Where I should specify value for that option?**

I have tried changing value in ~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/hinterland/hinterland.yaml, but without success.